# A function to check if a file has been changed

Tags: shell-script, zsh

so i'm trying to make a function that will check if a file has been modified using this function:

located in `functions.zsh`:

```
changed() {
  echo "$1"
  if [ -f "$1_changed" ]; then
    if [ stat -f "%Z" != $(<"$_changed") ]; then
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    fi
  else
    stat -f "%Z" "$1" > "$1_changed"
    return 1
  fi

}
```

The current use case is this:

located in `load_plugins.sh`:

```
if [ changed("plugins") -eq 1]; then
  echo "plugin file updated, installing plugins"
  antibody bundle < "$plugin_file" > "$installed_plugins"
  if [[ $OSTYPE == *darwin* ]];then
    antibody bundle robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh folder: lib/clipboard >> "$installed_plugins"
  fi
fi
```

both of which are sourced like this:

located in `~/.zshrc`

```
base_path="$HOME/.zsh"
config_path="$base_path/config"

source "$custom_path/functions.zsh"
source "$config_path/load_plugins.zsh" "$config_path"
```

the problem is I get this error:

```
load_plugins.zsh:7: number expected
```

which is this line:

```
if [ changed("plugins") -eq 1]; then
```

I've also noticed that if I place:

```
echo changed("plugins")
```

before:

```
if [ changed("plugins") -eq 1]; then
```

Nothing is printed out to the terminal, same thing for the `echo` within `changed()` which I placed to check if the function was working.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Changes I've made so far:

```
changed() {
  echo "$1"
  if [ -f "$1_changed" ]; then
    if [ "$(stat -f \"%Z\")" != "$(<"$1_changed")" ]; then
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    fi
  else
    "$(stat -f "%Z" "$1")" > "$1_changed"
    return 1
  fi

}
```

#### FINISHED WORKING VERSION

```
changed () {
  local timestamp="$(stat -f %Z "$1")"

  if [ ! -f "$1_changed" ] ||  [ "$timestamp" != "$(<"$1_changed")" ]; then
    current="$(<"$1_changed")"
    printf '%s\n' "$timestamp" >"$1_changed"
  fi

  [ "$timestamp" != "${current:-$(<"$1_changed")}" ]
}
```

Comment: Consider using [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for catching most common errors in your scripts.  The `stat -f` call on line 4 is not actually calling `stat`. Also the `[...]` test needs spaces within `[` and `]`.

Comment: @Kusalananda updated with some changes, no dice :(

Comment: Now you include the `"` in the `stat` output. There's no need to escape the double quotes there.

Comment: `stat -f '%Z' FILE` will give you the file's size in Darwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated function, with corrected quotes in a call to `stat` (the quotes would have been outputted and the later tests against the contents of the file would have *always* failed due to them):

```
changed() {
  echo "$1"
  if [ -f "$1_changed" ]; then
    if [ "$(stat -f "%Z")" != "$(<"$1_changed")" ]; then   # escaped quotes removed
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    fi
  else
    "$(stat -f "%Z" "$1")" > "$1_changed"      # note: error here
    return 1
  fi

}
```

This may be shortened significantly into:

```
changed () {
  echo "$1"

  if [ ! -f "$1_changed" ]; then
    stat -f %Z "$1" >"$1_changed"
    return 1
  fi

  [ "$(stat -f %Z)" != "$(<"$1_changed")" ]
}
```

Here, I've also turned a command substitution that would have run the *output* of `stat` into a straight call to `stat`, redirected into the output file (see `error here` note in first piece of code).

I've also changed the logic of the function so that not so many `return` calls are needed.  If there is no `return`, the exit status of the function will be that of the last statement in the function.

We can make this slightly neater with

```
changed () {
  echo "$1"

  local timestamp="$(stat -f %Z "$1")"

  if [ ! -f "$1_changed" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$timestamp" >"$1_changed"
    return 1
  fi

  [ "$timestamp" != "$(<"$1_changed")" ]
}
```

Later, you may call this function using

```
if changed "$filename"; then
    # do something, the file in "$filename" changed
fi
```

Note that your call,

```
if [ changed("plugins") -eq 1]; then
```

has several syntax errors.

Comment: This almost works as Intended, see `FINISHED WORKING VERSION` for how I changed it.

Comment: @Thermatix Note that in your code, you may end up trying to read into `current` from an non-existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate four errors in

```
 if [ stat -f "%Z" != $(<"$_changed") ]; then
```

which are:

- use "command substitution" `$(...)`
- change `stat -f` to `-c` option
- add a file name (`$1`) for `stat` (later downstream as well!)
- use correct file name with `$1`

yielding

```
 if [ $(stat -c "%Z" "$1") != $(<"$1_changed") ]; then
```